# Mail not sending locally in ROR

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, mailer

I am trying to send mail locally but it doesn't send mail. What is actually happening....?

## Contoller

```
class ForestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_forest, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /forests
  # GET /forests.json
  def index
    @forests = Forest.all
  end

  # GET /forests/1
  # GET /forests/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /forests/new
  def new
    @forest = Forest.new
  end

  # POST /forests
  # POST /forests.json
  def create
    @forest = Forest.new(forest_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @forest.save

        UserMailer.welcome_user(@forest).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to @forest, notice: 'Your Message send successfully.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @forest }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @forest.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_forest
      @forest = Forest.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def forest_params
      params.require(:forest).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :body)
    end
end
```

## UserMailer

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "tayyabzahid96@gmail.com"

  def welcome_user(forest)
    @forest = forest
    mail(to: @forest.email, subject: "Hello Man", body: @forest.body)
  end
end
```

## View

```
= form_for :forest, url:{:action =>"create"}, html:{:class => "form-horizontal" } do |f|
  %div.form-group
    = f.label :name, 'Name', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'} 
    %div.col-lg-3
      = f.text_field :name, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Your Name"}
  %div.form-group
    = f.label :email, 'Email', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
    %div.col-lg-3
      = f.text_field :email, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "someone@example.com"}
  %div.form-group
    = f.label :phone, 'Phone', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
    %div.col-lg-3
      = f.text_field :phone, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Mobile No"}
  %div.form-group
    = f.label :body, 'Body', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
    %div.col-lg-3
      = f.text_area :body, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Your Message"}
  %div.form-group
    %div.col-lg-offset-2.col-lg-10
      = f.submit :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => "Contact Us"
```

What is  happening....? Why does it not send mail...? I can't understand the problem.... Any suggestion about this that will be helpful for me......????

Answer (score 1):

How did you configure mail in development.rb? The following works great for me:

```
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.   
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Change mail delvery to either :smtp, :sendmail, :file, :test
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: CONFIG[:mail_domain],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: CONFIG[:mail_username],
    password: CONFIG[:mail_password]   
  }
```

Comment: After add these in developemnt.rb file my server not started

Comment: Okay, not good - what do the log files say? BTW: Everything in the code saying "CONFIG[...]" should be replaced by proper values e.g. "user_name: 'ben@example.com'" or whatever you credentials are ...

Comment: it just replace the Config with my domain, username and password.... then its work....